# Positive Diode clipping circuits

Tags: circuit-protection

[image]

Why is the clipped voltage constant in the positive half for the first half of the cycle? Isn't it supposed to act as a ideal diode during forward bias ie behave as a closed switch?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please edit your title to give a summary of the question. "This is very confusing" is not a good title for a question about diode forward voltage drop.

Comment: Hello and welcome!  To get a good answer, I recommend you edit your question: 1) Crop the image to focus on the relevant info  2) Add more detail to your description of what the circuit is supposed to do, and what you don't understand about how it works.  3)  Edit your title to be more informative

Comment: Please post text as text.  Please don't post text as screenshots.  Text is searchable, but screenshots aren't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, no, this is not an example of an ideal diode.

Real diodes have a forward voltage drop of approximately 0.7 V (for silicon). When the diode is forward biased, its low impedance (relative to the series resistor) keeps the output voltage at 0.7 V relative to the 0 V at the cathode.

Answer (score 1):

> Isnt it supposed to act as a ideal diode during forward bias ie behave as a closed switch?

No. It's supposed to behave as a real diode that drops 0.7 V when forward biased.

The graph shows this clearly. On positive half cycles the diode is forward biased and the output is clamped at 0.7 V.